# How to pass a variable in index.html to a service?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-services, angular-services

Hey guys complete noob to angular. Can you help me?
So I have the following code provided by google oauth:

```
<script>
  function onSignIn(googleUser) {
    // Useful data for your client-side scripts:
    var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
    console.log("ID: " + profile.getId()); // Don't send this directly to your server!
    console.log("Name: " + profile.getName());
    console.log("Image URL: " + profile.getImageUrl());
    console.log("Email: " + profile.getEmail());

    // The ID token you need to pass to your backend:
    var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
    console.log("ID Token: " + id_token);
  };
</script>
```

This is index.html

I want to be able to access the given token from a factory that I have in angular. Is this through $scope?

```
App.factory('ranService', ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q) {

var service = {};
var randomUrl = "http://zzz;
var googleToken;


return service


}]);
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us the Angular service?

Comment: @Beto. check my answer. if it doesn't help, let me know

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
```

put this inside your controller and use ng-controller directive in your html file to use {{id_token}}.

Answer (score 0):

You can address this method through callback or just `onSignIn()//it returns id_token` after my changes

```
var profile;
function onSignIn(googleUser, callback) {
    // Useful data for your client-side scripts:
    if (googleUser)
        profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
    console.log("ID: " + profile.getId()); // Don't send this directly to your server!
    console.log("Name: " + profile.getName());
    console.log("Image URL: " + profile.getImageUrl());
    console.log("Email: " + profile.getEmail());

    // The ID token you need to pass to your backend:
    var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
    console.log("ID Token: " + id_token);
    //if there isn't success callback this callback use there  
    if (callback)
        callback(id_token);
    return id_token;
}
```

in your service:

```
angular.module('serviceModule')
        .service('Service', ['$q', '$http',
            function ($q, $http) {

                function sendRequest() {

                    onSignIn(null, function (id_token) {
                        //you use this
                    })
                    //or just
                    var idToken = onSignIn();//it can return without params 
                }

                return {
                    sendRequest: sendRequest
                }
            }]);
```

in controller:

```
Service.sendRequest();
```